# Detect Networks/communities and assign IDs

Tags: r, graph, igraph, plyr

i have a table which shows two columns having IDs. The below table implies that ID in column 1 is related to ID in column 2. The schema of table is such that we have both ( say IDs are A and B , both are related. Then entry will appear twice , once as A to B and B to A ) , sample table below :

```
ID.1    ID.2
 A       B 
 A       C
 B       C
 C       B
 C       A
 B       A
 D       E
 E       F
 F       E
 D       F
 E       D
 F       D
```

( e.g. for A,B,C we see A & B are related , A & C are related  , B & C are related - i tag all of them in one house and give a unique id )

Output

```
  ID.1    ID.2      HouseID
     A       B       X1
     A       C       X1
     B       C       X1
     C       B       X1
     C       A       X1
     B       A       X1
     D       E       X2
     E       F       X2
     F       E       X2
     D       F       X2 
     D       F       X2
     E       D       X2
     F       D       X2
```

How do i get the above in R ? what if i add a transitive logic for example A is related to B and A is related to C , Hence B also must know C  ?

Comment: A few keywords: in your 1st case, you're after (maximal) [cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)), whereas your 2nd case (with "transitive logic") is about [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)). Both cases can be addressed using [igraph](https://cran.r-project.org/package=igraph). Note that your 2nd case is well-defined, since connected components realize a partition of the graph. Your 1st case is not: a vertex can belong to 2 different maximal cliques.

Comment: Example for 2nd case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079559/make-a-group-indices-based-on-several-columns

Comment: @Scarabee - 2nd case inputs understood and easy to implement. From a definition standpoint i call the second case a community whereas first case i call a household - hence a person A can belong to multiple households and one community. This is what you imply by 'can belong to 2 different maximal cliques' ? How do i address this case

Comment: How can it detect ( A related to B , B related to C , A related to C , A related to  D ) are one house since a direct relation has been identified in all pairs from A and BC is captured in the same house id rather than a separate one  - pairs ( AB , AC , AD , BC)

Comment: Is there a way of doing these in Dplyr ?

Comment: I am using the same code as the link shared above , however i am getting NAs for the group values   `g <- graph_from_data_frame(df1[, c(2, 3, 1)])
myGroups <- components(g)$membership
df1$group <- myGroups[df1$G1]`

Comment: Yes it is what I imply. A person can belong to multiple households but you want only one HouseID column, so you have to choose one. / Despite your example, the way you identify households is still not clear enough for me. / No I don't think you could do it using only dplyr. / Using the sample you provided, `g <- graph_from_data_frame(df1[, 1:2]);myGroups <- components(g)$membership;df1$group <- myGroups[df1$ID.1]` does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the question, @Scarabee had it right. The answer depends on *maximal cliques*, but the bounty shows that the OP did not consider that a full answer. This answer pushes that through to assigning the `HouseID`.

```
library(igraph)

## Your sample data
Edges1 = read.table(text="ID.1    ID.2
 A       B 
 A       C
 B       C
 C       B
 C       A
 B       A
 D       E
 E       F
 F       E
 D       F
 E       D
 F       D", 
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

g1 = graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(Edges1), directed=FALSE)
plot(g1)
MC1 = max_cliques(g1)
MC1
[[1]]
+ 3/6 vertices, named, from 8123133:
[1] A B C

[[2]]
+ 3/6 vertices, named, from 8123133:
[1] D E F
```

This gives the maximal cliques (the houses), but we need to construct the HouseID variable.

```
Edges1$HouseID = apply(Edges1, 1, 
    function(e) 
        which(sapply(MC1, function(mc) all(e %in% names(unclass(mc))))))
Edges1
   ID.1 ID.2 HouseID
1     A    B       1
2     A    C       1
3     B    C       1
4     C    B       1
5     C    A       1
6     B    A       1
7     D    E       2
8     E    F       2
9     F    E       2
10    D    F       2
11    E    D       2
12    F    D       2
```

The outer `apply` loops through the edges.  The inner `sapply` checks which clique (house) contains *both* nodes from the edge.

This provides the structure that the question asked for. But as @Scarabee pointed out, a node may belong to more than one maximal clique (house).  That is not exactly a problem as the requested structure assigns the HouseID to *edges*.  Here is an example with a node that belongs to two houses.

```
Edges3 = read.table(text="ID.1    ID.2
 A       B 
 A       C
 B       C
 D       E
 D       A
 E       A", 
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

g3 = graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(Edges3), directed=FALSE)
plot(g3)
MC3 = max_cliques(g3)

Edges3$HouseID = apply(Edges3, 1, 
    function(e) 
        which(sapply(MC3, function(mc) all(e %in% names(unclass(mc))))))
Edges3
  ID.1 ID.2 HouseID
1    A    B       2
2    A    C       2
3    B    C       2
4    D    E       1
5    D    A       1
6    E    A       1
```

[image: Node A is in more than one maximal clique]

In this case, We can still assign a HouseID to each *edge*, even though the node A is in two different Houses. Notice that the edge A-B has `HouseID = 2`, but edge D-A has `HouseD = 1`.  The HouseID is a property of the *edge*, not the *node*.

However, there is still a problem. It is possible for both ends of an edge to belong to two houses and one cannot assign a single house to the edge.

```
Edges4 = read.table(text="ID.1    ID.2
 A       B 
 A       C
 B       C
 D       A
 D       B", 
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

g4 = graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(Edges4), directed=FALSE)
plot(g4)
MC4 = max_cliques(g4)
MC4
[[1]]
+ 3/4 vertices, named, from fbd5929:
[1] A B C

[[2]]
+ 3/4 vertices, named, from fbd5929:
[1] A B D
```

[image: Edge A-B is in two maximal cliques]

The edge A-B belongs to two maximal cliques.  As @Scarabee said, the question is not actually well-defined for all graphs.

Comment: thanks for the explanation . After Scarabee pointed out - i looked into graph theory to understand it. Broad problem to give you an idea is to -  understand from a data engineering standpoint that - given the address , emails and Policy relation ( Insurance ) first identify linkages or relations - This i have already populated i.e. the edges ( so called relations of A and B ), Now task was how to identify households in my customer data base. This answer gives me a good starting point , however if there is a better methodology that you can suggest , do share.

Comment: i wanted to define two things - Household ( All relations of edges at first level - A to B , B to C , A to C , A to D . Other thing was community which captured all relations including indirect relations . Ex A is related to B , B is related to C , hence A and C might know each other. Hence rather than calling it one house - i call it a community. This community by definition will have multiple houses. Purpose was to cater for scenarios like If A ( Father ) related to B ( daughter ) , B is related to C ( Husband ) which is now a different house and hence should not be clubbed as one

Comment: @Pb89 So examples where a node is in two houses certainly could happen (e.g. shared custody of a child after parents divorce and remarry), but for your problem, shared edges do not seem very likely..

Comment: The code you provided is going on a long run at `max_cliques(g4)` and after hours still hasn't finished - not sure if a desktop R will be able to handle it ? my data is huge with about 800k edges - would it be because of that ?

Comment: Yes.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem)  says that to find all maximal cliques has a worst-case complexity of `O(3^(n/3))` where n is the number of nodes. The `apply` - `sapply` part should be fast, but maximal cliques will be expensive if you have a lot of nodes.

Comment: i ran the code as shared. I am getting Same no of IDs as edges - i.e. it is not forming ids for a network as the case above but assigning each row( edges) an ID

Comment: It is not identifying maximum cliques properly . It is identifying A to B and A to C as separate and with 2 cliques and giving 2 IDs , is it some simple data format issue ? I am using in same format as shared by you above

Comment: @Pb89 Yes.  Your original question assigned IDs to _pairs_ of points,  ie edges. This code will do that too. Thus, a single node might be in several cliques. That is part of the point of the extra examples.  What would you want  the answer to be for the first picture above - the one with 5 nodes?

Comment: It should come under one house ID - for the picture with 5 nodes. But irrespective , shouldn't a simple A to B and A to C , have a same house ID as per your code ? While i can plot and see the edges but its reflecting in the House IDs where each edge is getting its own ID

Comment: @Pb89 Just to clarify,  I don't think that each _edge_ is getting a different HouseID, but rather each _clique_ is getting a HouseID. (That does mean that some nodes will be in two houses).     - - - I think that you answered that for the picture with 5 nodes,  you want only one HouseID. So you want B & E in the same House even though there is no direct connection between them? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes correct. I'll consider the indirect linkage between B and E in the same house ID. However like i pointed earlier - for some reason i am not getting house Id for _cliques_ but for each edge . So if my table has 25 edges for example , i am getting 25 IDs - using the same code as above. Not sure if its a data format related issue or something else ? Any alternative code suggested ? - Key thing is to generate the IDs

Comment: You see that on the original data that you provided, I got two IDs for 12 nodes.  Are you getting that as well?  It is only on your real data that it does not work? Or is it also giving 1 ID per edge on the sample data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152548/discussion-between-pb89-and-g5w).